# Connecting to localhost Neo4j database from remote device (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, neo4j, remote-access

Currently, my Neo4j database uses the address `http://127.0.0.1:7474`.

I have changed the file `neo4j-server.properties` so it now reads `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0` as it says to uncomment this line to allow remote access.

I have also tried `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=127.0.0.1` but when trying to access `http://127.0.0.1:7474` on my iPhone I cannot connect to the server.

Has anyone had any experience trying to do this?

Thanks as always

Comment: Why do you think 127.0.0.1 on your iPhone corresponds to 127.0.0.1 on your Neo4J box?

Comment: Aah youre completely right! I was going to say its the IP address they specify in the documentation, I changed it to my computers local IP address and now it works. If you want to add it or you want me to add it as the answer I'll happily set it as the correct answer

Comment: Added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the localhost IP to the address of your computer running Neo4J.